# How to make random thread wait then wake it up after constant time

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

In my main thread I create and start four threads(`A,B,C,D`) which print letter and number on the console every 500 to 1000ms.
For instance `A1,A2,A3` etc.

The main thread suppose to pause random `Letter` thread every 100ms then wake it up. After 2 seconds it suppose to kill them all.

My problem is that I can't pause random `Letter` thread then wake it up because I get: `IllegalMonitorStateException`

My Main thread class:

```
public class Main extends Thread {
    private boolean alive;
    private ArrayList<Letter> letters;
    private Letter toStop;
    public static Object mutex;

    public Main() {
        letters = new ArrayList<Letter>();
        alive = true;
        mutex = new Object();
    }

        public void run() {
    try {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new StopTask(timer, this), 2 * 1000);
        letters.add(new Letter());
        letters.add(new Letter());
        letters.add(new Letter());
        letters.add(new Letter());
        for (Letter letter : letters) {
            new Thread(letter).start();
        }

        while (alive) {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                toStop = letters.get((int) (Math.random() * letters.size()));
                System.out.println(toStop.getLetter() + " spi");
                mutex.wait();
                Thread.sleep(100);
                mutex.notify();
            }
        for (Letter letter : letters) {
            letter.kill();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    public void kill() {
        alive = false;
    }

}
```

and my `Letter` class:

```
class Letter implements Runnable {
    private static int ID;
    private char letter;
    private int counter;
    private boolean alive;

    public Letter() {
        letter = (char) ('A' + ID);
        alive = true;
        ID++;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (alive) {
                System.out.println(letter + "" + counter);
                counter++;
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 501 + 500));
            }
            System.out.println("Watek " + letter + " sie zakonczyl");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void kill() {
        alive = false;
    }

    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

}
```

`StopTask`:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class StopTask extends TimerTask {
    private Timer timer;
    private Main main;

    public StopTask(Timer timer, Main main) {
        this.timer = timer;
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Time's up!");
        main.kill();
        timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit
    }
}
```

Comment: You are synchronizing on `mutex` and calling `wait()` on `toStop`. You should call `mutex.wait()` instead

Comment: @NitinDandriyal but I want pause the `toStop` until I call notify.

Comment: @NitinDandriyal I updated the `run` in `Main` the threads never end. I added `StopTask` so now, the copied code will compile and run.

Comment: You must first understand that to call wait and notify on any object you must first acquire the monitor of that object using `synchronized` keyword, otherwise you'll get this Exception. Re-write your code keeping this in mind.

Comment: urrently your `mutex` is visible only to main Thread, rest of the `Letter` Thread don't know and don't care about it, hence is no sense of placing a wait and notify in Main Thread with current  code

Comment: @NitinDandriyal I know about it hence I posted the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example does not work because the wait() call is made without owning the object's monitor.

Here is the javadoc explanation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

Here is a snippet from the javadoc:

> public final void wait()
>                   throws InterruptedException
>
> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object. In other words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call wait(0).
>   The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.
>
> As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor. See the notify method for a description of the ways in which a thread can become the owner of a monitor.
>   Throws:
>   IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.
>   InterruptedException - if any thread interrupted the current thread before or while the current thread was waiting for a notification. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

I would redesign the code to make the thread wait itself rather than being told to wait from outside. For instance, use some shared objects to share the state among threads. 
I would also use the scheduled thread executor. Makes life easier:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: You should always append important code snippet in your answers, because links might not work or might get removed, thus snippets work

Comment: Please take a look at modified code. The letters never stop to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a typical Producer-Consumer problem and there are better ways to do it. Since we are solving the problem at hand you can do below.

You can get rid of mutex Object and use the `Letter` instance as mutex, so effectively you have 4 mutex's each co-ordinating with `Main`

```
public class Main extends Thread{
    private boolean alive;
    private ArrayList<Letter> letters;
    private Letter toStop;
    //public static Object mutex;

    public Main() {
        letters = new ArrayList<Letter>();
        alive = true;
        mutex = new Object();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new StopTask(timer, this), 2 * 1000);
            letters.add(new Letter());
            letters.add(new Letter());
            letters.add(new Letter());
            letters.add(new Letter());

            for (Letter letter : letters) {
                new Thread(letter).start();
            }

            while (alive) {
                // synchronized (mutex) {
                toStop = letters.get((int) (Math.random() * letters.size()));
                synchronized (toStop) {
                    //System.out.println(toStop.getLetter() + " spi");
                    // mutex.wait();
                    //Thread.sleep(100);
                    // mutex.notify();
                    toStop.setToGetLetter(true);
                    toStop.notify();
                }
                System.out.println(toStop.getLetter() + " spi");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            // }
            for (Letter letter : letters) {
                letter.kill();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void kill() {
        alive = false;
    }
}
```

And in your `Letter` Thread, you can use `this` to co-ordinate with Main

```
public class Letter implements Runnable {
    private static int ID;
    private char letter;
    private int counter;
    private boolean alive;
    private volatile boolean toGetLetter = false;

    public boolean isToGetLetter() {
        return toGetLetter;
    }

    public void setToGetLetter(boolean toGetLetter) {
        this.toGetLetter = toGetLetter;
    }

    public Letter() {
        letter = (char) ('A' + ID);
        alive = true;
        ID++;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (alive) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (!isToGetLetter()) {
                        this.wait();
                }
                System.out.println(letter + "" + counter);
                counter++;
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 501 + 500));
                toGetLetter = false;
                this.notify();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Watek " + letter + " sie zakonczyl");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

    public void kill() {
        alive = false;
    }

    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }
}
```